Adding Touch function to PowerShell using based on this. But I have an issues regarding pathing
I am doing LearnPythonTheHardWay and one of the exercises requires me to use the Touch function in PowerShell.
As I found out, it needs to be added as per the below link indicates, yet I have encountered an issue where the path to my profile cannot be found (or accessed?)
What am I missing?
I am trying to update my profile based on this
Issue as below:

I am using PowerShell version 5.1.19041.4648

The (current-user, current-host) profile file, whose full path is reflected in the automatic $PROFILE variable, may not yet exist on your system.
• To create it on demand, run if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { New-Item -Force $PROFILE }
• To edit it with Visual Studio Code, for instance, run code $PROFILE or, if no custom text editor is installed, use
notepad $PROFILE. See the linked duplicate for details.
